# Prevent Drawer Menu from showing when keyboard is present? (Android Appcelerator)

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I would like to prevent the user from opening the navigation drawer menu when the keyboard is present. I tried adding "focus" and "blur" listeners to the TextField:

```
$.searchField.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('locked drawer');
    $.drawerLayout.drawerLockMode = Titanium.UI.Android.DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED;
});

$.searchField.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('unlocked drawer');
    $.drawerLayout.drawerLockMode = Titanium.UI.Android.DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED;
});
```

But as you can see nothing happens:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have done similar to this using **[NL Fokke Drawer Widget](https://github.com/FokkeZB/nl.fokkezb.drawer)**.

Using this widget, I have created my windows like this:

***XML:***

```
<Alloy>
  <Widget id="drawer" src="nl.fokkezb.drawer">
    <View module="xp.ui" role="leftWindow">

    </View>

    <NavigationWindow module="xp.ui" platform="ios" role="centerWindow">
        <Window>
            <Require src="homeView"></Require>
        </Window>
    </NavigationWindow>

    <Window module="xp.ui" platform="android" role="centerWindow">
        <Require src="homeView"></Require>
    </Window>
</Widget>
```

***JS:***

```
// to close the drawer   
$.drawer.instance.setDrawerLockMode($.drawer.module.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);

// to unlock the drawer
$.drawer.instance.setDrawerLockMode($.drawer.module.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

If you are not using this widget, then I believe you can match your code with this widget's code & see how it's setting up the lock modes.

Comment: I know the methods to lock/unlock the drawer, but what I want is to lock the drawer when the user is typing on the TextField (when the keyboard is present), and unlock it when the keyboard is not present.

Comment: Are your focus & blur events not firing up? because the rest of the code seemed fine to me.

Comment: Yes, my events are not firing up.

Answer (score -1):

Add this code code an your Activity

```
    @Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    View v = getCurrentFocus();
    if (v != null &&
            (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) &&
            v instanceof EditText &&
            !v.getClass().getName().startsWith("android.webkit.")) {
        int scrcoords[] = new int[2];
        v.getLocationOnScreen(scrcoords);
        float x = ev.getRawX() + v.getLeft() - scrcoords[0];
        float y = ev.getRawY() + v.getTop() - scrcoords[1];
        if (x < v.getLeft() || x > v.getRight() || y < v.getTop() || y > v.getBottom())
            hideKeyboard(this);
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}

public void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    if (activity != null && activity.getWindow() != null && activity.getWindow().getDecorView() != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Appcelerator Titanium, not native development.

Comment: sorry @guillefix  i have no idea

Comment: @RameshYogu, please try to properly review the question before putting answer. It was clearly showing that this question is for Titanium.